# moodle auto login as a guest on the front page

Tags: moodle

On Moodle 2.8 we have plugins that require you to log in as a guest, in order to use the plugins. Now currently Moodle will allow auto login if you navigate to a course that allows guest access, but we require it to auto login the moment you hit the index (front page), without having to click on login then click on guest login.

Is there perhaps a url, for example:

```
http://moodle.mydomain.com/index.php?guest_login
```

That We could get Apache to redirect to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this with 2 configuration settings.

1. enable `autologinguest`

   go to site admin -> users -> permissions -> user policies

   or direct to /admin/settings.php?section=userpolicies
2. set `guestloginbutton` to Show

   go to site admin -> plugins -> authentication -> manage authentication

   or direct to /admin/settings.php?section=manageauths